# Apply purrr::map to a sequence of elements of nested list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I need to purrr::map several elements of a nested list. For example, `map(list,1)` gives me the 1st element of each list in the nested list. The problem is that I need to apply it several times. How could I apply it in a sequence of pre-defined numbers? Example as follows:

```
# Nested list
df <- list(
list(
 seq(0,100, length.out = 1000),
 seq(0,500, length.out = 1000),
 seq(0,700, length.out = 1000)),
list(
 seq(200,300, length.out = 1000),
 seq(500,5000, length.out = 1000),
 seq(200,900, length.out = 1000)
 )
)

# My sequence
myseq <- seq(1,3, by = 1)
```

I would like to do something like `map(df,myseq)` in order to automatically do the sequence: `map(df,1)`, `map(df,2)`, and `map(df,3)` but of course it does not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `purrr::transpose(df)`

Comment: this is great!!